# What are the main reasons for passenger server shut down periodically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

In my rails application, I am using

`Apache + ruby 1.9.2p180 + Rails 3.0.5 + Phusion Passenger version 3.0.13`

Can somebody please tell me why my passenger shut down periodically. Somebody please help

```
This is the last error after which the application stops working

[Fri Aug 31 02:07:23 2012] [error] [client 141.212.121.10] Premature end 
of script headers: 
[ pid=17952 thr=1 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:817 time=2012-08-31 
02:07:23.257 ]: The backend application (process 13680) did not send a 
valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible 
that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in 
this application. 
[Fri Aug 31 04:20:55 2012] [notice] child pid 27795 exit signal 
Segmentation fault (11) 
[Fri Aug 31 04:20:56 2012] [notice] child pid 22071 exit signal 
Segmentation fault (11) 
[Fri Aug 31 04:21:03 2012] [notice] child pid 13025 exit signal 
Segmentation fault (11) 
[Fri Aug 31 04:21:04 2012] [notice] child pid 24538 exit signal 
Segmentation fault (11) 
[Fri Aug 31 04:21:06 2012] [notice] child pid 17065 exit signal 
Segmentation fault (11)

I am using 
ruby 1.9.2p180 
Rails 3.0.5 
Phusion Passenger version 3.0.13
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does 'egrep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages' say?

Comment: My passenger server is again shut down today with same error. I am not able to find out what exactly error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says : "please check whether there are crashing bugs in 
this application."

Did you try to remove your web application, and try with a simple index.html page ?

If it's stable then the issue doesn't come from Passenger config, but rather in your application.
In this case, increase the log verbosity by adding loger in your application at each step there is a user interaction.

Check also that you are using apache2-mpm-prefork and not apache2-mpm-worker.
This apache2-mpm-worker is a multi-thread version, and unfortunately passenger doesn't support multi-thread with apache2.
Try following commands to check wether it is installed or not :

```
aptitude show apache2-mpm-worker
aptitude show apache2-mpm-prefork
```

What does this command shows ?

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

You should have everything green.

Comment: +1 for help thanks, But my passenger again shut down don't know why?

Comment: Check your log/developement.log file to see what was the last error before the crash.

Comment: Then the issue may likely come from apache, passenger or an apt packet related to them. TO be sure check William answers with  'egrep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages'. If I remember correctly Rails kills request taking more than 0.5 secondes. What is doing your app ?

Comment: I accept the answer because it's work around for trace out problem. But i am not able to trace it out yet..