# How can i downgrade the version of java from 1.6.0 to java 1.5.0 on Sun Solaris 11

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solaris, rjb

I have my system configuration on live server of Joyent

```
Sun Solaris 11
Ram 8 GB
HD 240 GB
VM 16 GB
```

I have already installed `Java 1.6.0` on my server machine
and i am running my `Ruby on rails` application on server.

For application i am using,

```
Ruby 1.9.2p180 
Rails 3.0.5 
Phusion Passenger version 3.0.13
```

It's not running fine and my application shut down periodically [Passenger Shut Down Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063234/what-are-the-main-reasons-for-passenger-server-shut-down-periodically).

I think `RJB(Ruby Java Bridge) is not compatible with Java 1.6.0. So i want to downgrade my java version to Java 1.5.0.`

How can i downgrade it?

Does it effect to my application?

Somebody please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally, you install the version of Java you want to use and make sure it is the one in your `PATH`. Note: Java 6 is about to be end of line so I would look at ways to upgrade.

Comment: Why do you not try to uninstall the 1.6 and install 1.5? I think this change will not effect your application because your it need java 1.5

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, Thanks but RJB is only compatible with Java 1.5.0 can you please tell me how can i downgrade it on Solaris machine?

Comment: "you install the version of Java you want to use and make sure it is the one in your PATH"

Comment: @Festado, Thanks it's my live server can i take a risk of it? And how can i do it on Solaris?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, Can i set PATH mannually?

Comment: @SumitMunot The installation is quite easy http://192.9.162.55/j2se/1.5.0/install-solaris.html. To avoid risks because of your live server. Please check first whether any other application running on the server depends of 1.6

Comment: @SumitMunot I cannot think of any reason you cannot. It is the same on Solaris as it is on all Unixes e.g. Linux and much the same as on Windows (the syntax is slightly different)

Comment: If you don't want to alter the existing system, you can unpack Java as a sub-directory.  I always do this in any case and I don't much advantage to installing it into the OS.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, Can you please mention how do i unpack Java as sub-directory?

Comment: @SumitMunot Download it and run the shell script which unpacks the software.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I am little bit confused. How can i maintain the multiple version of java on same OS of solaris? i typed command which java? then it displays '/opt/local/bin/java' and In which file i need to set for the PATH like in .cshrc, .bashrc, ENV.or .profile. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to uninstall, simply install 1.5.0 (if you can get it it)  and create a JAVA_HOME variable in the environment to point to 1.5.0 -  Putting it in PATH may mess up other code, I do not know what you have running.

Comment: something else is really not right.  The current version from oracle of the JDK and JRE is 1.7xxx which might be  a better choice if in fact java version is the problem at all.

Comment: Thanks but if my jdk 1.5 is not working can i revert back to the previous version which i already have.

Comment: Do not use JAVA_HOME, unset the variable.  I think you probably need 1.7.  Each java install goes into a separate subdirectory, so installing a new version breaks nothing if you do not change the existing PATH variable.  JAVA_HOME is only used to circumvent the PATH setting.  So you can use several different versions, on a per app basis.